# Why does this error happen when swap for same type of standard library containers with a custom comparator?

Tags: c++, lambda, swap, std

I encountered a compile error on this code. I don't understand why my compiler throws an error when I was just adding a custom comparator.

```
using P = pair<int, int>;
auto comp = [](auto&l, auto&r) {
    return l.second > r.second;
};
priority_queue<P, vector<P>, decltype(comp)> pq1(comp), pq2(comp);
pq1.swap(pq2); // error!
```

and the error is like

```
In file included from /opt/wandbox/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/queue:64,
                 from /opt/wandbox/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/stdc++.h:86,
                 from prog.cc:1:
/opt/wandbox/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/bits/stl_queue.h: In instantiation of 'void std::priority_queue<_Tp, _Sequence, _Compare>::swap(std::priority_queue<_Tp, _Sequence, _Compare>&) [with _Tp = std::pair<int, int>; _Sequence = std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >; _Compare = main()::<lambda(auto:23&, auto:24&)>]':
prog.cc:10:13:   required from here
/opt/wandbox/gcc-10.1.0/include/c++/10.1.0/bits/stl_queue.h:696:6: error: no matching function for call to 'swap(main()::<lambda(auto:23&, auto:24&)>&, main()::<lambda(auto:23&, auto:24&)>&)'
  696 |  swap(comp, __pq.comp);
      |  ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

with a bunch  more as well.

@NathanOliver, thanks for the information!
I created three workarounds for the example above.

```
int main() {
    using P = pair<int, int>;
    auto comp = [](auto&l, auto&r) {
        return l.second > r.second;
    };
    priority_queue<P, vector<P>, function<bool(P&, P&)>> pq1(comp), pq2(comp);
    pq1.swap(pq2);
    return 0;
}
```

```
int main() {
    using P = pair<int, int>;
    function<bool(P&, P&)> comp = [](auto&l, auto&r) {
        return l.second > r.second;
    };
    priority_queue<P, vector<P>, decltype(comp)> pq1(comp), pq2(comp);
    pq1.swap(pq2);
    return 0;
}
```

```
using P = pair<int, int>;
class Comp {
public:
    bool operator()(P& l, P& r) {
        return l.second > r.second;
    }
};

int main() {
    priority_queue<P, vector<P>, Comp> pq1, pq2;
    pq1.swap(pq2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Either include the error message or post a [mcve] (so we can copy into an online compiler) please

Comment: Can you add the exact text of the error message and I mean text no pictures of your screen.

Comment: [Your code can be compiled without errors](https://wandbox.org/permlink/y1Cn5a4Pm0bMA0sm), but errors appeared when I lowered C++ version. What error do you get? Which C++ version are you using?

Comment: @RichardCritten They should do both for ideal chances of getting good answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Pre C++20

Closures (what a lambda expression creates) are not copy/move assignable.  In order to swap something it needs to be copy/move assignable and since it isn't, the code will fail when using a closure type for the comparator.

### C++20

non-capturing lambdas are copy assignable so this code will now work if you use C++20 as the standard to compile against.

Comment: @Jinchul You can use a `std::function` instead of using `decltype(comp)`.  You could also just write a functor like you did.

Comment: Thanks for your kind comment. Would you please provide us a complete code for the declaration of a variable(i.e. priorty_queue)?

Comment: @Jinchul For your original code you could change `priority_queue<P, vector<P>, decltype(comp)> pq1(comp), pq2(comp);` to `priority_queue<P, vector<P>, std::function<bool(P&, P&)>> pq1(comp), pq2(comp);`